# Image and link are not rendering inside HTML table

Tags: html, css

I have a table with fields having images and links. But it gives code instead of rendering it.

```
<table id="table" 
             data-toggle="table"
             data-search="true"
             data-filter-control="true" 
             data-show-export="true"
       data-show-refresh="true"
       data-show-toggle="true"
       data-pagination="true"

             data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       class="table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
            <th data-field="prenom" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Title</th>
            <th data-field="date" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Price</th>
            <th data-field="examen" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Image</th>
            <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true">Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Maths Tution</td>
            <td>$20</td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0GoaYKd.jpg" height="100" width="100"></td>
            <td><a href="https://monsoonmalabar.com/sonyshop/other/product-13/">Go</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="1" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Milk</td>
            <td>$5</td>
            <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2ZOroMI.jpg" height="100" width="100"></td>
            <td><a href="https://monsoonmalabar.com/sonyshop/test_category_2/product-6/">Go</a></td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
      </div>
```

Here is the link to the website, https://www.monsoonmalabar.com/aggregate_search

How to render the html here?

Comment: Your above code is fine but the code which is in your website is not fine, when I edit the code in the firebug image tag braces show in ascii-code instead of symbol `<td style="">&lt;img src="https://i.imgur.com/0GoaYKd.jpg" height="100" width="100"&gt;</td>` you need to replace ascii-code into symbols like `<td style=""><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0GoaYKd.jpg" height="100" width="100"></td>`. After this change, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap Table escapes HTML tags. Add `data-escape="false"` in your `table` tag.

https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#escape